# Graphing - Absolute Value and Circle

Tags: inequality, graphing-functions, problem-solving, absolute-value

The diagram Shows The Graphs of $y = |x + 2|$ and $y = \sqrt{4 - x^2}$

[image: Diagram]

Write down the solution for $\sqrt{4 - x^2}$ is equal to or less than $y = |x + 2|$.

Comment: What are your thoughts on this question? The answer should be obvious from the graph.

Comment: Well they are saying that to prove that the circle is equal to or less than the absolute value graph. Are they referring to certain points on the graph where the absolute value line is equal to and greater than the circle?

Comment: Yes. They are asking, for which values of $x$ is the absolute value graph above the semicircle graph.

Comment: Like when y = 2, both abs value line and circle are equal?

Comment: Well, maybe you should see it this way: as $x$ varies, you can think of the circle as $y_1=\sqrt{4-x^2}$ and the line as $y_2=|x+2|$, so for what values of $x$ is $y_2\geq y_1$?

Comment: x is less than or equal to -2 and when x equal to and greater than 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints: you need to solve the inequality

$$\sqrt{4-x^2}\le |x+2|\implies 4-x^2\le x^2+4x+4\implies x^2+2x\ge 0$$

Remember that when you solve inequalities *by squaring sides*, you **must** check each and every "solution" you get at the end in the *original* inequality (why?)

Comment: how do you translate y = |x + 2| to a quadratic?

Comment: @MATHSUSER: $0<a<b\longrightarrow 0<a^2<b^2$

Comment: OHHHHHHHHH!!!!!!! I think i understand! but wouldn't the quadratic have two possibilities since the Absolute value? or no?

Comment: @MATHSUSER , in fact $$|x+2|^2=(x+2)^2=x^2+4x+4\;\ldots$$

Comment: So the answer is x <= 0 and x > -4

Comment: But remember what I wrote after "remember" in my answer, @MATHSUSER ...! For example, the definition domain of $\,\sqrt{4-x^2}\;$ is pretty small, isn't it...?

Comment: 0 <= x <= 2 ? yes?

Comment: Well yes @MATHSUSER...but that contradicts your past comment, which was in fact wrong: it should have been that $\;x\le -2\;\;or\;\;x\ge 0\;$ , and taking into account the domain thing we'd get, as you did (I've no idea how) that in fact $\;0\le x\le 2\;$ ...

Comment: Well I solved the Inequality as you asked me. And I did get that x = -2 and x = 0 and then from how you normally solve inequalities from there I got the answer.

Comment: But in your comment above you said you got $\;x\le 0\;$ **and** $\;x>-4\;$ , or what is the same: $\;-4<x\le 0\;$ , which is **not** what you wrote afterwards.

Comment: Oh, that's because I solved it wrong and I found that those values didn't work, so I decided to re-do the inequality from the start and I got this answer and It worked. Sorry for confusing you. Also thank you for all your help and everyone else that assisted.

Comment: Anytime @MATHSUSER , it was fun.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: You are asked to write down the values of x for which $\sqrt{4-x^2}\le|x+2|$. What would you do to remove square root and mod?

Comment: I understand that y^2 + x^2 = 4, but what do i do after that? Simultaneous equations? (Sorry if I sound stupid).

Comment: Solve the equation that I have written.

Comment: Well if i solver them separately the absolute value would have to possible solutions?

Comment: Why would you solve them separately? It is one equation now. If it helps then in rough work, try solving $\sqrt{4-x^2}=|x+2|$. Can you do it?

Comment: Thanks Ramit I think I understand what I'm Doing now.

Comment: That's good....